# How to keep fixed footer in Android webview from covering input field when soft keyboard comes up?

Tags: android, html, css, reactjs, webview

I have a webview that is a react app (not react native). It is a login page with two input fields and a fixed footer.

When the input is focused the footer comes up and overlaps the input field hiding the password input field.

What can I do so the footer stays under the keyboard?

[image]

Comment: Is the footer css position set to fixed? Also, one hacky idea would be setting the footer to display:none whenever the input is focused. Anyway, posting your css might be a good idea! =)

Comment: Another workaround is to use media queries. If you know in which height it needs to stop sticking to the bottom, then use `@media (max-height:<height>)` then inside there set its `position` to `relative` (instead of `absolute` as default). I also add extra `margin-top` to add more space.

Answer (score 2):

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

set this onCreate method of your activity

Comment: I think yes but not tried. you can try it out by putting in manifest or java activity if there

Comment: Yea I have this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" but it's not working

Comment: there are other solution but i am busy once i free i will let you know